# Ffmpeg - Playback of HTTPS link via proxy CLI

Tags: ffmpeg, proxy, https, tls

I want to play a video but I need to connect via a proxy.  I noticed that the link is http connection via `http_proxy` is not a problem but in the case of https you have to use the environment variable for the proxy to work - running it via CLI is not possible, I need it badly.

I found several sources that talk about the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468662/ffmpeg-add-proxy-to-request

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7223

[HTTP/HTTPS Proxy and FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1317240/http-https-proxy-and-ffmpeg)

Here's the consumption in the code source.  We have CLI support for HTTP.  HTTPS/TLS does not have.
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/642404f28d39cefb7857c0d77c3a4e5ac98e62c6/libavformat/http.c#L207

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/642404f28d39cefb7857c0d77c3a4e5ac98e62c6/libavformat/tls.c#L92

I am surprised that this option is not available yet, I would like to add it myself, but I cannot code in C/C++.

Comment: If your final goal is to download a video from a https address, did you try [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/)? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42948404/1256347) explains how you can specify a proxy,

Comment: Perhaps you can share your final goal? It's hard to guess over the internet.

Comment: As mentioned in the topic, I want to download the video, but to do that I need to connect via a proxy. There is no greater purpose here - if I may put it that way.

Comment: Ok. But then I don't understand why my suggestion for using youtube-dl with the proxy option is not something you want to look at. Did you try youtube-dl to download the video? If you check the link you'll see it's not only for youtube.

Comment: youtube-dl does not allow me to download and play at the same moment and convert the video.

Comment: That's clear. Can you perhaps add the new requirement of playing back *and* recording at the same time to your question? It's a different question than what you're asking now...
Also, feel free to show what you have done so far in terms of websearches, or what command you've tried.

Comment: I added a few links from which I got information and corrected the title and the content a bit.